# Customize properties for MSDeploy via Nant or VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, nant, msdeploy

I have a web application that I want to deploy using MSDeploy.
I have a Nant script that runs MSBuild and has the property DeployOnBuild set to true. It creates a deployment package that I use on a server.

What I want to do is to avoid that MSDeploy deletes the content of the destination folder before it deploys the new files. I can do it manually by adding -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule to my command line, but I would like MSDeploy to do it manually. I really need some help with that.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and if there was a way to make this setting from there it would be optimal. If it's possible to do it from Nant that also great.

Summary:
The deployment package created with MSBuild via Nant should have the flag -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up using the Nant command for creating a bat file, and then we added the -enableRule to the command in that file:

```
<echo file="..\..\Packages\${stage}\${project::get-name()}.${stage}.Run.TestDeploy.bat">
        %CD%\${project::get-name()}.${stage}.deploy.cmd /T -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule
        PAUSE
    </echo>

    <echo file="..\..\Packages\${stage}\${project::get-name()}.${stage}.Run.REALDEPLOY.bat">
        %CD%\${project::get-name()}.${stage}.deploy.cmd /Y -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule
        PAUSE
    </echo>
```

The /T and /Y flags are used in MSDeploy to know whether you are testing the script (/T) or if you're running it for real (/Y).

This is a workaround, but we're satisfied with it.

Answer (score 3):

Set the property $(SkipExtraFilesOnServer) to the value "true", either in a project or shared import file,

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>true</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
</PropertyGroup>
```

or on your command line from Nant,

```
/p:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=true
```

See the file Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (search for "MSDeploy") for more options.

Comment: Thank you for your input. We did try this solution but unfortunately it didn't work. I will post an answer about how we got around the issue.